# iOS/objective-c: Spooky error setting value of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, set

I have copied some code that works fine for saving an api to one entity in core data over to save a similar api to another entity.  Although everything is largely the same, I cannot get rid of exception error.

Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) convertFeedtoObject:(NSMutableArray*)feed {
    NSMutableArray * _newitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *feedElement = feed[i];

        ItemOnServer *newItem = [[ItemOnServer alloc] init];
        newItem.itemtitle = feedElement[@"itemtitle"]; //throws exception
        newItem.item = feedElement[@"item"];//also throws an exception if above commented out
         newItem.descript = @"some item"; //if above lines commented out, littoral throws exception too.
//same goes for any other values I try to set.  The first one throws exception.
```

Here is the error:

```
2015-11-20 05:26:03.281 [20610:60b] -[ItemOnServer setItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175721b0
```

No matter what values I try to set, I get a similar error even though I know the values are there.

One item of the feed looks like this:

```
 {
        lastviewed = "2015-11-17 15:21:45";
        itemtitle = "New";
        id = 944;
        item = "cotton shirt";

    }
)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
Edit:

Code from ItemOnServer.h

//.m file is largely empty
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class ItemsVC;
@class Vendors;

@interface ItemOnServer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * item;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;//this is permanent id shared with server
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * localid; //this is temp id if first created locally
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastviewed;

//this is relationship with vendors
@property (nonatomic, retain) Vendors *vendor;

@end
```

Comment: can you paste the code of "ItemOnServer" class

Comment: Yeah, the problem here is that creating the NSObject classes like your ItemOnServer class is hard to manage with "null" values from a server or any other inordinary data that comes from the server side. What I normally do to work around this the first time when developing is I don't build object models until after I verify that the data stream is returning the data I want each time. I instead just use NSMutableOrderedSets to test the data, after all, OrderSets aren't sets, they are merely subclasses of NSObjects, but they handle data better tha your own implementation ever will

Comment: pasted code.  I hear you about null values but I've set up api to only provide one record with all values present and still throwing exception so I think it must be something else in this case.  Also when I test for nil/null throws same exception.

Comment: @Larcerax: null values or nil values are not the problem (yet). It's the call to the setItem: method that doesn't succeed because there is no implementation.

Comment: put a breakpoint after NSDictionary *feedElement = feed[i]; and check if feed[i] has actual values inside it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class ItemOnServer doesn't have implementations for the methods setItem:, setItemtitle and so on. I don't know how you managed to do this, but you should look at the interface and implementation of ItemOnServer.

Look at what the error message says:

```
 -[ItemOnServer setItem:]: unrecognized selector
```

That means a setItem: message is sent to an object, that object is an ItemOnServer object, and it doesn't implement setItem: The first two of these three points are exactly what you expect to happen when you write newItem.item = ...

Do you have another class named ItemOnServer in your application, maybe linked through some library? You can easily check by renaming ItemOnServer with ItemOnServer2 and checking what happens.

Comment: I don't explicitly have set methods for the other class where I do this from which I copied the above code.  Are they required?

Comment: Using dot notation, doesn't this happen seamlessly behind scenes?

Comment: I renamed the class and tried to rebuild it and now it won't compile, saying Linker command failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `NSDictionary` declare feedElement as an `NSMutableArray`, so something like:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) convertFeedtoObject:(NSMutableArray*)feed {
    NSMutableArray * _newitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *feedElement = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.count; i++) {
        feedElement = feed[i];

        ItemOnServer *newItem = [[ItemOnServer alloc] init];
        newItem.itemtitle = feedElement[@"itemtitle"];
        ...
```